# Combining p-values for averaging technical protein quantification replicates in python

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, combining-p-values

I have some data about protein expression levels in a cell. For each identified protein, there is an expression level and an associated p-value indicating the confidence that the protein was identified correctly. Two of the samples were technical replicates (i.e. a single sample was split into two parts and analysed separately). I now need to average the expression levels of the two technical replicates, and their corresponding p-values. I thought to use [Fisher's method](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fishers_method) to combine them, which seems to me like the right thing to do. The problem is that I need to convert the result from a $\chi^2$ value into a p-value. Excel has a CHIDIST function which seems to do the trick, but, since I'm likely to be doing this sort of thing a lot in the near future, I thought to write a script to do it to plug into our analysis pipeline. I'm using python to write it, but can't find an equivalent function to CHIDIST. I realize that the process is basically finding the probability of getting the given $\chi^2$ score, so I'd like to check my thinking.

1. Am I doing the right thing combining the p-values?
2. Is Fisher's Method the appropriate process for combining the p-values?
3. How many degrees of freedom? I'm thinking 2, as per the Wikipedia page.
4. The final p-value is one minus the integral from negative infinity to the $\chi^2$ score over the $\chi^2$ probability density function with one degree of freedom -- is this correct?

Comment: (1) Where does the one degree of freedom in (4) come from?  (2) The complementary CDF for $\chi^2(2)$ is simply $x\to \exp(-x/2)$.

Comment: With respect to Python and finding the analog to Excel's CHIDIST function, Scipy has what you need in the scipy.stats.chi2 class. For example,  1 - chi2.cdf(5, 3) = CHIDIST(5, 3) = 0.171797

Comment: @whuber, sorry the 1 was a typo, and the replacement (2) was a misreading of the formula for fisher's method. DF should be 2k where k is the number of tests combined (in my case 2), so it should be 4

Comment: @JoshHemann, thanks, this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: With four df, Fisher's Method gives $p_1 p_2 (1 - \log(p_1 p_2))$.  In general, for other (even) degrees of freedom, the result does not require calculating chi-squared distributions; it is a polynomial in the product of the $p_i$ and its logarithm.  For $n$ tests, instead of 2, the formula is $x\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-\log(x))^k/k! $ for $x=p_1p_2\ldots p_n$.

Comment: Someone, like @JoshHemann or whuber should probably write it as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @whuber , do you know where I can find a reference for this formula? I opened a new question with that topic: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/199581/36056

Answer (score 6):

**To combine p-values** means to find formulas $g(p_1,p_2, \ldots, p_n)$ (one for each $n\ge 2$) for which

1. $g$ is symmetric in its arguments;
2. $g$ is strictly increasing separately in each variable; and
3. $P=g(P_1,\ldots, P_n)$ has a uniform distribution when the $P_i$ are independently uniformly distributed.

**Symmetry** means no one of the $n$ tests is favored over any other.  **Strict increase** means that each test genuinely influences the combined result in the expected way: when all other tests remain the same but a given p-value gets larger (less significant), then the combined result should get less significant, too.  The **uniform distribution** is a basic property of p-values: it assures that the chance of a combined p-value being smaller than any level $0 \lt \alpha \lt 1$ is exactly $\alpha$.

For many situations these properties imply that when the $p_i$ are p-values for independent tests of hypotheses, $g(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ is a p-value for the null hypothesis that all $n$ of the separate hypotheses are true.

[Fisher's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) is

$$g(p_1,\ldots, p_n) = 1 - \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^{-\log(p_1p_2\cdots p_n)} t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt.$$

Properties (1) and (2) are obvious, while the third property (uniform distribution) follows from standard relationships among uniform and Gamma random variables.

**I claim the integral can be eliminated, leaving a relatively simple algebraic function of the $p_i$ and their logarithms.**  To see this, define $$F_n(x) = C_n\int_0^x t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt$$ where $$C_n =\frac{1}{(n-1)!} = \frac{1}{n-1}C_{n-1}$$

(provided, in the latter case, that $n \ge 2$).  When $n=1$ this has the simple expression

$$F_1(x) = \int_0^x e^{-t}dt = 1 - e^{-t}.$$

When $n\ge 2$, integrate by parts to find

$$\eqalign{
F_n(x) &=\left. - C_n t^{n-1} e^{-t}\right|_0^x + (n-1)C_n \int_0^x t^{n-2}e^{-t}dt \\
&= -\frac{x^{n-1} e^{-x}}{(n-1)!} + F_{n-1}(x).
}$$

Apply this $n-1$ times to the right hand side until the subscript of $F$ reduces to $1$, for which we have the simple formula shown above.  Upon indexing the steps by $i=1, 2, \ldots, n-1$ and then setting $j=n-i$, the result is

$$F_n(x) = 1 - e^{-x} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{x^{n-i} e^{-x}}{(n-i)!} = 1 - e^{-x}  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^j}{j!}.$$

Write $p=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$ for the product of the p-values.  Setting $$x=\log(p) = \log(p_1)+\cdots+\log(p_n)$$ yields

$$\eqalign{
g(p_1,\ldots, p_n) &= 1 - F_n(-x) = p \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{(-x)^j}{j!} \\
&=p_1p_2\cdots p_n \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^j \frac{\left(\log(p_1)+\cdots+\log(p_n)\right)^j}{j!}.
}$$

---

This is most useful for its insight into combining p-values, but for small $n$ isn't too shabby a method of calculation in its own right, provided you avoid operations that lose floating point precision or create underflow.  (One method is illustrated in the `R` code below, which computes the logarithms of each term in $g$ rather than computing the terms themselves.)  Here are the formulas for $n=2$ and $n=3$, for instance:

$$\eqalign{
g(p_1,p_2) &= p_1p_2\left(1 - \log(p_1p_2)\right) \\
g(p_1,p_2,p_3) &= p_1p_2p_3\left(1 - \log(p_1p_2p_3) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\log(p_1p_2p_3)\right)^2\right).
}$$

The terms in parentheses are factors (always greater than $1$) that correct the naive estimate that the combined p-value should be the product of the individual p-values.

---

```R
Fisher.algebraic <- function(p) {
  if (length(p)==1) return(p)
  x <- sum(log(p))
  return(sum(exp(x + cumsum(c(0, log(-x / 1:(length(p)-1)))))))
  #
  # Straightforward (but numerically limited) method:
  #
  n <- length(p)
  j <- 0:(n-1)
  x <- sum(log(p))
  return(prod(p) * sum((-x)^j / factorial(j)))
}
Fisher <- function(p) {
  pgamma(-sum(log(p)), length(p), lower.tail=FALSE)
}
#
# Compare the two calculations with one example.
#
n <- 10 # Try `n <- 1e6`; then try it with the straightforward method.
p <- runif(n)
c(Fisher=Fisher(p), Algebraic=Fisher.algebraic(p))
#
# Compare the timing.
# For n < 10, approximately, the timing is about the same.  After that,
# the integral method `Fisher` becomes superior (as one might expect,
# because of the two sums involved in the algebraic method).
#
N <- ceiling(log(n) * 5e5/n) # Limits the timing to about 1 second
system.time(replicate(N, Fisher(p)))
system.time(replicate(N, Fisher.algebraic(p)))
#
# Show that uniform p-values produce a uniform combined p-value.
#
p <- replicate(N, Fisher.algebraic(runif(n)))
hist(p)
```