# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the distribution of p-values

Tags: multiple-comparisons, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a set of independent null hypothesis significance tests and their resulting p-values and I would like to make the claim that they are not all null by looking at the distribution of independent p-values. Since under the (meta) null hypothesis that all my hypotheses are actually null, the distribution of p-values is uniform, I though that I could simply perform a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test on that distribution and report the resulting p-value. Is this legitimate and is this something that any of you has seen done before? If so, would you have a reference?

I know of false discovery rate by Storey and Tibshirani but I would really wish to have a single p-value for the whole distribution rather than a set of q-values.

Comment: I would advise approaching this cautiously.  First, many tests do not produce exact p-values: they are approximate.  Second, others do produce excellent p-values only when the p-values are small.  Third, a test statistic with a discrete distribution obviously cannot yield a uniform distribution of p-values.  Fourth, you're concerned about a specific alternative hypothesis, where the density of the p-value distribution grows at the lower values and shrinks at the higher, so this calls for a specialized test. The first three imply that a test of uniformity might give misleading results.

Comment: Have you seen https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20616?